# Execute commands from python prompt using os.system

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to execute a few commands using python shell to import a module ABC. For that I have created a python file `test.py` having the following lines:

```
import os
os.system('python')
os.system('import ABC')
```

Now I am trying to execute that file as follows - `python test.py`. Here, it runs till the 2nd line i.e. `os.system('python')` properly. Then when it enters into the python prompt and there it remains stuck as it is not command prompt any more but python prompt. So how to execute the next command of importing the module ABC on the python prompt?

Comment: Why would you want to launch the Python shell from a Python script to run in that shell?

Comment: Actually I have to invoke many python commands like "import ABC" from the python shell. So wanted to automate that by writing a script so that can run all those at one go.

Comment: @RDX IMHO Python shell is for the convenience of **interactive** use, while script is for the convenience of **non-interactive** use, you had better make it clear in which way you want to use Python, do not mix up, it seems to make the the situation more complicated.

Comment: @rustyhu, let me explain you my case. I have many python api's to execute manually from the python shell. So instead of running those manually, I tried to run them as part of one script. So please share your views how to run all the python api's at one go ?

Comment: @RDX 1. Copy and paste all these things you need to input manually into repeatly; 2. Put all these things into `tmp.py` in cwd, then when you need them in shell, execute `from tmp import *`

Answer (score 1):

**Command line and environment ([Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html))**

```
python [-bBdEhiIOqsSuvVWx?] [-c command | -m module-name | script | - ] [args]
```

In your terminal, when you run python followed by the name of a script (test.py), you are executing the contents of the script. Within that script, when you call 'python' using os.system('python'), you are starting a new interactive session, similar to if you were to just call 'python' from your terminal.

```
import os
os.system('python -c "import ABC"')
```

Comment: This works. But in my case I have to run multiple commands. So after running  - os.system('python -c "import ABC"'), if I run (say) os.system('python -c "ABC.add()"'), then it is not running saying "
NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined" as I think it terminated the previous session which I had opened using - os.system('python -c "import ABC"'). So how to run the multiple commands in the same python shell ?

Comment: @RDX
I think what you want is the subprocess module. See  [Replacing os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

The `shell=True` might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-c` argument with `python`.
For example,

```
import os
os.system('python -c "import ABC"')
```

Comment: This works. But in my case I have to run multiple commands. So after running  - os.system('python -c "import ABC"'), if I run (say) os.system('python -c "ABC.add()"'), then it is not running saying "
NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined" as I think it terminated the previous session which I had opened using - os.system('python -c "import ABC"'). So how to run the multiple commands in the same python shell ?

Comment: Anytime you want to run a function in the `ABC` module in a different command, you have to import it again. Alternatively, you can run it all in one command with:                            `python -c "import ABC; ABC.add()"` What's important is that you seperate each sub command with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is to put the commands you require in a Python script, e.g. `my_imports.py`:

```
import ABC
import my_module
```

And run it from interactive Python with something like:

```
exec(open('my_imports.py').read())
```

That will execute the code in the script in the current context, making the imports available to you on the Python CLI.